# Как перенести фоновый blur из фигмы на css?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, figma

Сделал макет на фигме(первый) и не понимаю как в css реализовать blur, который за изображением в css. Помогите пожалуйста[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы не воспользоваться свойством `box-shadow`? Пример:

```css
body {background: #001f21;}

div {
  width: 100px; height: 100px; position: absolute; top: calc(50% - 50px); left: calc(50% - 50px);
  box-shadow: 0 0 100px 20px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я просто только начинаю, поэтому многого не знаю.